# In webpack --watch I only see the first error

Tags: javascript, webpack

When compiling a project in `webpack` using the `--watch` option, if the project has an error for example in the `less` compiler I see that error in the output. Once I correct the error `webpack` recompiles and all is well.

However if there are multiple errors in the file and I only fix one of them, when `webpack` re-compiles the code it does not show the new error message, in fact the console does not update at all.

For example:

1. `less` file has two errors and save the file
2. `webpack --watch` attempts to compile the file and fails, showing the first error
3. I fix the first error and save
4. `webpack` **does not** show the second error

How can I tell `webpack` to show the error of the updated build after if fails for a second time?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that this option is not available on `webpack cli` but you can easily create a plugin to listen for build events and output any errors, i.e.:

```
const ConsoleNotifierPlugin = function () {}

ConsoleNotifierPlugin.prototype.compilationDone = (stats) => {
  const log = (error) => {
    console.log(error.error.toString())
  }
  stats.compilation.errors.forEach(log)
}

ConsoleNotifierPlugin.prototype.apply = function (compiler) {
  compiler.plugin('done', this.compilationDone.bind(this))
}
```

Then just add it to the plugins:

```
...
plugins: [new ConsoleNotifierPlugin()]
...
```

Comment: I had to add `new`: `plugins: [ new ConsoleNotifierPlugin()]`

Comment: Thank you for this.